# search google images by image from file in python

Tags: python, image, search, drag-and-drop

I am trying to rename the images in my massive pictures folder by searching google images by each image and naming them the result next to "Best guess for this image: ". I understand that google does have a python API but I am unsure if it can be used in this way, or if that is a reasonable project for someone of my limited experience.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages#Uploading seems to be helpful but I'm not sure I understand what I need to be doing conceptually.

Another option is to use the drag-and-drop feature but I have not looked into that as much.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide#json_snippets_python) could be of some use perhaps if I uploaded the pictures

Comment: maybe if I used file:///... ? I'll test it out and post the results

Comment: no luck so far. have been trying to automate the uploading task by pulling a url list from imgur, calibrating the mouse locations, and using the win32 api to click the appropriate locations. doing it this way will take some time but I will upload when finished unless someone can produce a better method.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google still doesn't offer a public API for its reverse image search service (i.e. you send a picture and get textual search results).

The most popular alternative that I know is TinEye ( http://www.tineye.com/ ). Here's a link to their RESTful API: http://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI

Comment: I had not checked for an alternative. Unfortunately TinEye is unable to find adequate names for most of the pictures. I suspect google will be the best service but with no API I might have to settle.